# Round SQL String Data to correct decimal place, then return string data without floating point errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, rounding

We are trying to implement a reporting system using software that queries our SQL database.  Due to a variety of circumstances, we have a need to round data within the SQL queries.  Our goal is to avoid floating point errors, unwanted trailing zeros, and complexity of nested functions (if possible).

The incoming data is always type nvarchar(...) and needs to remain in a string format, which is causing problems for us.  Here is an example of what I mean (tested using w3schools.com):

```
SELECT 
STR(235.415, 10, 2) AS StringValue1,
STR('235.415', 10, 2) AS StringValue2,
STR(ROUND(235.415, 2),10,2) AS RoundValue1,
STR(ROUND('235.415', 2),10,2) AS RoundValue2,
STR(CAST('235.415' As NUMERIC(8,2)),10,2) As CastValue1
```

And, the result:

[image: SQL Output]

I know that the issue is a conversion to floating point data type when handling strings.  I think the last option, i.e. casting to numeric, is the answer to my issue.  However, I can't tell if this output is correct because the CAST guarantees there will not be an error, or because I got lucky for this specific instance.

Is there any type of SQL round function (or combination of functions) that takes string input, outputs string data, and doesn't involve floating point arithmetic? -- Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUMERIC/DECIMAL and MONEY don´t uses floating point arithmetic. The are in fact integers with a fixed comma.

Be aware that if you have large sums or do some calculations with these values, your rounding error can get pretty big, pretty fast. So it is advisable to take some moments to think about where you store a value with which precision and when you want to round.